There appears to be multiple projects that contain bitcoinlib in their name
Should questions about the "bitcoinlib" installed with pip be tagged under "python-bitcoinlib"?
They're clearly two different projects, and fortunately python-bitcoinlib uses the namespace bitcoin and the version of bitcoinlib installed via pip uses the namespace bitcoinlib. Are there other projects that could cause naming conflicts as well?

It seems to me that Peter Todd's python-bitcoinlib should be tagged as python-bitcoinlib, while bitcoinlib should be tagged as bitcoinlib. Unfortunately it appears there is a .NET library under the same name though, and bitcoin-lib-php which is similar.
